# Read, Modify and Update on AWS S3 atomically

Tags: java, amazon-s3, microservices, distributed-system

I have a use case where I need to mutate the S3 object.
How I am trying to achieve this is as follows:

```
Person person = getObject(key);
person.setAge(46);
saveObject(key, person);
```

The problem with the above code is that when another thread tries to modify the city of the same person simultaneously, this may lead to inconsistency.

I have tried using the following way too by acquiring lock on the key of the object as follows:

```
ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object> lockMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

public void saveObject(String key, Person person) {
  Object lock = null;
  synchronized(lock = lockMap.getOrDefault(key, new Object())) {
    lockMap.put(key, object);
    Person person = getObject(key);
    person.setAge(46);
    saveObject(key, person);
  }
  lockMap.remove(key); // don't want map to grow in size.
}
```

This way I can achieve atomicity but in distributed context (with multiple nodes of microservice) this would fail as atomicity can not maintained across all nodes.

Is there any workaround to achieve the same or AWS S3 provides something already built for this purpose?

Answer (score 2):

S3 does not provide a mechanism to handle this. You will have to build a distributed locking mechanism using another service like DynamoDB. I suggest evaluating if these objects should be stored in S3 at all, as this really looks like a good use case for DynamoDB or another NoSQL database.

Comment: Can we make this work for now by just stroing locks in S3 only. I know we will have to get the lock, and then delete the lock from S3 after use. Its okay to loose performance for now.

Comment: @Ruman Do you already use any storage in your application, like an RDBMS or Redis? If you do, you can implement your lock there.

Comment: No Dbms or Redis is being used in the application. How about storing the locks in S3 itself? @svetha.cvl